# How to add an html email signature to outlook 2010

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I have created an email signature in HTML and would like to use it in Outlook 2010. However, there are few things I am getting stumped on.

*Some preface info*:

(I included my logo, and four social media icons with links in my signature. I just uploaded the images to dropbox and linked to them in my code)

My code opened fine and looked as it should it my browser, so I saved the code to the signatures folder. I went to compose a new message and tried inserting my signature, but no dice. Outlook recognizes that the signature exists in the signature folder, but when I click on it, it isn't included in the message.

I read [here](https://spinwebnz.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/how-to-add-an-html-signature-file-to-outlook-2007/) that Outlook needs 3 different files (in .htm, .txt and .rtf formats). in order for a signature to work. But I'm not convinced that this is the case. To test this theory, I went to [htmlsig.com](http://www.htmlsig.com) and created a signature. It was just a simple html document. I downloaded the signature and saved it to the signature folder. I then opened Outlook, created a new message, and was able to insert *that* signature just fine.

I opened up the signature folder to see what kinds of files were in there, and the only file in there was a single Chrome HTML document.

*My question*:

How can I add my html file to be used as an email signature?

In case you were curious, here is my source code: (Its a work in progress)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ccjrncxekbz4k1p/Transparent%20logo.jpg?dl=0" alt="MidWest Quality Gloves" border="0" class="sig-logo" height="115" width="133">
  </p>
  <p class="social-list" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">

    ##facebook##
    <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline;" class="social signature_facebook-target sig-hide" href="https://www.facebook.com/MidwestGlove/">
      <img width="33" style="margin-bottom:2px; border:none; display:inline;" height="33" data-filename="facebook.jpg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/42pre6zyk40xa98/Facebook.jpg?dl=0" alt="Facebook">
    </a>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline;" class="signature_facebook-sep social-sep">
      
    </span>
    ##instagram##
    <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline;" class="social signature_instagram-target sig-hide" href="https://www.instagram.com/midwestglove/">
      <img width="33" style="margin-bottom:2px; border:none; display:inline;" height="33" data-filename="instagram.jpg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dmrbysqop83moq8/instagram.jpg?dl=0" alt="Instagram">
    </a>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline;" class="signature_instagram-sep social-sep">
      
    </span>
    ##pinterest##
    <a style="display: inline; text-decoration: none;" class="social signature_pinterest-target sig-hide" href="https://www.pinterest.com/mwglove/">
      <img width="33" style="margin-bottom:2px; border:none; display:inline;" height="33" data-filename="pinterest.jpg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9ejjex9wzksbvy3/pinterest.jpg?dl=0" alt="Pinterest">
    </a>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline;" class="signature_pinterest-sep social-sep">
      
    </span>
    ##LinkedIn##
    <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline;" class="social signature_linkedin-target sig-hide" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/midwest-quality-gloves-inc">
      <img width="33" style="margin-bottom:2px; border:none; display:inline;" height="33" data-filename="linkedin.jpg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/b6ceobojyt3zjle/linkedin.jpg?dl=0" alt="linkedin">
    </a>
    <span style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline;" class="signature_linkedin-sep social-sep">
      
    </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Back in the time when i used outlook 2010 i remember that i had to go to the Signatures panel and create a new one with some text. Then went to:

```
C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

Edited the .htm signature file that was created and replaced the content with my html code, saved and restarted outlook. Can't really explain for certain why and how.

Comment: We are still using `Outlook 2010`. I can confirm that the signature files are under "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures". I keep my `.txt`, `.htm` and `.rtf` signature files in this directory. To prevent unwanted changes, I set the files to read-only, unless I want to edit them.